# Анимация в Jypiter Notebook на windows

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

У меня не линукс и после упорного гуглиния не получается запустить анимацию.

```
#plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] ='C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg  \\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'
! pip install ffmpeg

 

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

# Создадим нужную фигуру
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax.set_title('Очень крутой график синуса')
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.set_xlim([0, 2 * np.pi])
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 5), ['0', 'π/2', 'π', '3π/2', ''])
ax.legend()

# Создадим линию, в которую будем класть данные
sinus_line = ax.plot([], [])[0]

# Скопируем код с ссылки выше
# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    sinus_line.set_data([], [])
    return (sinus_line,)

# animation function. This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    y = np.sin(x * i / 10)
    sinus_line.set_data(x, y)
    return (sinus_line,)

# call the animator. blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

 

#HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
# FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
#anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer = FFwriter)\

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in __getitem__(self, name)
    160         try:
--> 161             return self.avail[name]
    162         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'ffmpeg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a0cf571597cf> in <module>
      2 # FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
      3 #anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer = FFwriter)\
----> 4 Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
      5 HTML(anim.to_html5_video())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in __getitem__(self, name)
    162         except KeyError:
    163             raise RuntimeError(
--> 164                 'Requested MovieWriter ({}) not available'.format(name))
    165 
    166 

RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Путь `'C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg  \\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'` выглядит крайне подозрительно. Используйте модуль `pathlib` для указания путей.

Например:

```
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath

path = PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe')

print(str(path))
```

Comment: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available

Comment: @ karmik не сработало

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova что не сработало? Что вы сделали?

Comment: @ karmik вместо   plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] ='C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg  \\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'  вставила from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe')

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova вы уверены что `plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']` должен являться объектом `PureWindowsPath`? В исходном коде у вас строка там была

Comment: так у меня закомментрирвана эта строка

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova это же ваш код, откуда я знаю что в вашем коде есть `plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']`? :) Мне кажется логичным, что вы должны объект типа `PureWindowsPath` перевести в строку `str` нужного вам формата. Для этого есть куча функций, почитать про которые можно в доке https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib. Например, `str(path)`.

Comment: спасибо, почитаю.